# How is WPF's DependencyObject implemented?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

Are there any articles that describe how the `DependencyObject` class in WPF works "under the hood"?

Specifically, I'm curious about how dependency properties are stored and accessed efficiently.

Comment: There's a little bit of detail [here in this blog post](http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/01/19/inside-dependencyobject-dependencyproperty/). That's all I can find though.

Comment: A good thing to Google is dependency properties sparse storage

Comment: Have a look here as well http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property

Comment: Use a decompiler, you'll see the code. If you do not understand everything going on MSDN

Comment: Also a TODO in [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.Windows/DependencyObject.cs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As we know, a dependency property can be defined only on types that subclass DependencyObject. This base class defines a key value dictionary, that contains the local values of dependency properties.

When a dependency property is accessed, it's value is dynamically resolved (via the GetValue(dependencyproperty) in the .Net wrapper). For greater detail, check here: http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html